# ScrollView in Android app, only in half of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a question: i have an activity that i want her to look like:

---

### title

button1  --------------big space------------special button1

button2 --------------big space------------special button2

button3
.
.
.
.

### .

I will explain: i want a list of dynamic buttons, depend the number that i have in database. These are button1,2,3... buttons.

I want also 2-3 static menu buttons, which are used for orders like delete, add etc'.

So far what i did:
create static buttons - no problem.

create ScrollView of dynamic buttons depend db - no problem.

The problem is that the ScrollView  is hiding all my screen even if i have only one dynamic button. I want it to be as i was drawing - half of screen or even less.

I built the ScrollView  only in Java, not in XML also. Maybe this is my mistake?
I'm a bit confused from all this issue. Can you guide me please how to create a dynamic ScrollView that will be shown only in a small part of the screen?

The code for ScrollView , i took from another post here:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout home_linear = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
ll.addView(tv);

//loop- print buttons from db.

this.setContentView(sv);
```

Comment: PLease post xml file also

Comment: That's the point - i didn't create one. I only printed buttons to screen with loop.